# Dynamic text replacement based on URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, dom, cookies

So here's what I'm trying to accomplish here.

I know that server-side scripting would be best here, but I'm looking for more of a drop-in solution and I'm wondering if anyone has done this before.

Anyways, I'm looking to have wwww.example.com/service-page?cityname, and whichever cityname variable is in the URL will rewrite a class on the page to whatever the city name is.

For instance, if the url is wwww.example.com/service-page?Los-Angeles, then you would have text on the page be Los Angeles Plumbers or whatever the service is.

And then I want to take it a step further and use a cookie to replace any other website pages that have this class name. Is there any way to do this without using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Give your parameter a name like this:

www.example.com/service-page?city=Los-Angeles

Then use this code:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var city = getParamaterByName('city');
```

This should get you started?

Comment: It really does sound like a job for a server side scripting language though... By using javascript, you're going to have ALL your content on the page and then hide/show it, which is very innefficient in terms of the size of your HTML document.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Thanks for the help.